# Mercurial Glob Syntax to Match Characters in File Name

Tags: mercurial

I'm have a time trying to figure out the syntax to ignore files that match a certain pattern, namely: Com.Example/Com.Example.DomainModel23012013101705.somefileextension. The variable seems to be the date that is munged into the file name (23012013101705)

I have tried [0-9].somefileextension and other patterns all to no avail.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex not a glob.  Mercurial support both wherever it supports either.  In a `.hgignore` that would be:

```
syntax: regexp
[0-9]\.somefileextension
```

That regex matches your attempted glob, but you could, of course, narrow it more like:

```
syntax: regexp
^Com\.Example/Com\.Example\.DomainModel\d+\.somefileextension$
```

Comment: Too wide regexp, and, sorry, grep() verify content, not filename (AFAIK)

Comment: @LazyBadger I built the regexp to match the askers glob -- I agree I'd use a narrower one myself.  You're right about `grep()` how embarassing.

Comment: Just changed my hgignore file to use the more restrictive version .. spot in .. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Ry4an, sadly, made mistake. Grep() doesn't work with filenames.

**My "Proving Ground"**

```
>dir /B
.hg
404.php
archive.php
archives.php
comments.php
footer.php
functions.php
header.php
html5.js
image.php
index.php
license.txt
links.php
page.php
readme.txt
screenshot.png
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style.css
```

**Tests**

```
>hg locate "set:grep(html5)\.php"
hg: parse error at 11: invalid token
```

---

```
>hg locate "set:grep(html5)"
header.php
readme.txt
```

Note: found **files, which have text** "html5" in it, but **not file** html5.js

---

```
>hg locate "set:s[a-z]+\.php"
abort: \.php not under root

>hg locate "set:s[a-z]+.php"

>hg locate "set:s[a-z]+"
hg: parse error at 7: not a prefix: end

>hg locate "set:s\w+"
hg: parse error at 4: not a prefix: end
```

All tests with `set:` prefix and regexps failed

---

Different glob-patterns with set:

```
>hg locate "set:s**.php"
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php

>hg locate "set:s**.*"
screenshot.png
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style.css

>hg locate "set:s**e.*"
single.php
style.css
```

---

Regexp-patterns in filesets

```
>hg locate "re:s[a-z]+.php"
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php

>hg locate "re:s[a-z]+."
screenshot.png
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style.css
```

**Resume**

`hg forget "re:Com\.Example\.DomainModel[0-9]+\.somefileextension$"`

or

`hg forget "set:Com.Example.DomainModel**.somefileextension"`

and the same set to hgignore

Comment: Unfortunately, I was only concerned with the hgignore and didn't test the file code, on the other hand the regex did work in my rudimentary test. Thank you for the follow-up.